# How can I look up a static variable in a function with lldb?

Tags: c, static, lldb

I have a function like this (I've omitted most of the function for brevity):

```c
const char *
insn_name(VALUE i)
{
    static const char x[] =
        "nop" "\0"
        "getlocal" "\0"
        "setlocal" "\0";
    ...
}
```

I would like to get access to `x` from lldb.  nm is able to find the symbol:

```
$ nm -C miniruby | grep insn_name.x
00000001002cafa0 s _insn_name.x
00000001002ccbb0 s _insn_name.x
00000001002cdaf0 s _insn_name.x
```

I can print the address from lldb just fine:

```
(lldb) p (char*)0x1002cafa0
(char *) $45 = 0x00000001002cafa0 "nop"
```

I can look up information about the address:

```
(lldb) target modules lookup -Av -a 0x1002cafa0
      Address: miniruby[0x00000001002cafa0] (miniruby.__TEXT.__const + 11440)
      Summary: miniruby`insn_name.x
       Module: file = "/Users/aaron/git/ruby/miniruby", arch = "x86_64"
       Symbol: id = {0x0000263f}, range = [0x00000001002cafa0-0x00000001002cbb30), name="insn_name.x"
```

lldb must know about this thing, but I can't seem to figure out the command to look it up by name.  Eventually I would like to find this address via Python in an lldb extension.

Thank you.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function. Then the variable will be in scope and you can access it.

Comment: I'm debugging with a core file, so I need to access it later

Comment: In gdb I think you can refer to `insn_name::x`. See if that works in lldb.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. :(

Comment: gdb's use of :: to mean "function_name::static_variable_in_function_name" is handy but when debugging C++, "::" ends up not being a great choice for the separator.  We haven't come up with a workable way to spell that construct for the "p" command yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
image lookup -s insn_name.x
```

where `image` is a builtin lldb synonym for `target modules`.